# TestNG An internal error occurred during launching source not found

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I created a TestNG class (SampleTest.java) and when I run the test case as TestNG Test, I am getting the following error.

Launching Sample Test has encountered a problem.

An internal error occurred during: "Launching SampleTest".

source not specified

Stack Trace:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: source not specified
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createAST(ASTParser.java:813)
    at org.testng.eclipse.util.param.ParameterSolver.getParserNode(ParameterSolver.java:135)
    at org.testng.eclipse.util.param.ParameterSolver.parseParameterNames(ParameterSolver.java:125)
    at org.testng.eclipse.util.param.ParameterSolver.solveParameters(ParameterSolver.java:112)
    at org.testng.eclipse.util.param.ParameterSolver.getParameterNames(ParameterSolver.java:90)
    at org.testng.eclipse.util.param.ParameterSolver.solveParameters(ParameterSolver.java:59)
    at org.testng.eclipse.ui.util.ConfigurationHelper.getLaunchSuites(ConfigurationHelper.java:422)
    at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.createVMRunner(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:296)
    at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launchTypes(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:161)
    at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

Eclipse Version: Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)

Please Help!!!

Comment: I think the [Error Log View](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-error_log_view.htm) could provider further information on it. You might have to do another attempt running the test case after showing the view.

Comment: @Izruo  ,Please find the Stack Trace in Error Log

Comment: @izruo Hi , I tried to remove a source folder  from build path and added it back again , which surprisingly worked . Thanks !!